# Unable to import facebook SDK for Targetting search API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-business-sdk

I was trying to use Targetting search API from facebook business SDK API.

ImportError: No module named facebookads.adobjects.targetingsearch

Using Python 2.7.12
~

Was trying to execute this piece of code:

```
from facebookads.adobjects.targetingsearch import TargetingSearch
params = {
'q': 'un',
'type': 'adgeolocation',
'location_types': ['country'],
}

resp = TargetingSearch.search(params=params)
print(resp)
```

Actual result :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
from facebookads.adobjects.targetingsearch import TargetingSearch
ImportError: No module named facebookads.adobjects.targetingsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Marketing API docs a bit outdated. You should replace the import from:

```
from facebookads.adobjects.targetingsearch import TargetingSearch
```

to:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.targetingsearch import TargetingSearch
```

Also, before requesting targeting data, you should initialize FacebookAdsApi with your generated access token:

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)
```